# CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '1.4.0.85725' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, assemblyfileversion

(Please excuse me if I get any terms mixed up here - I am a Java developer, new to .Net and C#. Please add/correct any tags on this question if need be.)

I am using an MSBuild script to build my project. One of the tasks is to write the assembly info:

```xml
<Target Name="UpdateAssemblyInfo">
    <Message Text="Updating assemblies to file version $(AssemblyVersion) ($(AssemblyFileVersion))" Importance="high"/>
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
                  OutputFile="SharedAssemblyInfo.cs" 
                  AssemblyVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"
                  AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyFileVersion)"
                  AssemblyProduct="SVN revision $(BUILD_NUMBER)"/>
</Target>
```

This converts `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs` from this:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("0.0.0")]
```

To this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18063
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("1.4.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersion("1.4.0.85725")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProduct("SVN revision 85725")]
```

So far so good. Except I see the following message in the build log of TeamCity:

> CSC warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '1.4.0.85725' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format

Why am I getting this warning, when the format of the version appears to follow the format specified in the warning message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error is because the revision number is greater than 65534.

Comment: I guess that explains why, when I look at the properties of a DLL build, the **Product version** is **1.4.0.85725** while the **File version** is **1.4.0.20189**.

Answer (score 4):

> Why am I getting this warning, when the format of the version appears to follow the format specified in the warning message?

Re-read that warning, with some added emphasis:

> the normal 'major.minor.build.**revision**' format

.NET version numbers have FOUR parts, not three.

The [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) type used for this will process versions of fewer types, but it is possible for code using `System.Version` to check and be stricter.

Additional, as noted by [Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221036/67392), elements of the version are limited to [`System.UInt16.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.maxvalue.aspx) (65535): this is a Windows API limitation (in System.Version each element is a [`System.Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) related to the native [`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup> resource that the compiler inserts into the assembly from various assembly attributes. This allows tools like Windows Explorer to read the version.

Summary:

- There should be *four* parts to the version.
- Each part should be in the range [0, 65535].

---

<sup>1</sup> The version is stored across two `DWORD` members: one for Major and Minor parts, the other for Build and Revision (albeit not given those names in Win32).